# How to use getStaticProps without async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, callback

As a thought experiment and also to deepen my understanding of asynchronous programming, I would like to use the Next.JS [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props) method without utilizing `aysnc/await` syntax. In fact, I would like to do it using only callbacks. I am running into trouble and wondering if this is possible. I'm thinking it must be since `async/await` is just syntactic sugar for promises, which themselves are syntactic sugar for callback hell, correct?
Here is my `getStaticProps` function:

```
export function getStaticProps() {
    let products;
    let productPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '/data/products.json')

    // the async call
    fs.readFile(productPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        products = JSON.parse(data);

    });
    return {
        props: { products }
    }
}
```

The return value must be an object with a `props` property, which itself has the data meant to be passed to page component for rendering. I am lost on how to accomplish this with just callbacks. I know `async/await` is much more straight forward, but again, I'd like to learn.

Comment: "*promises are syntactic sugar for callback hell*" - [not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572). Your function is not actually returning a promise, and not taking a callback either (which next.js doesn't support)

Comment: async/await is syntatic sugar for promises, that's probably where the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return promise since your code is not synchronous. You can do it without `await` by creating the promise manually:

```
export function getStaticProps() {
  let productPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '/data/products.json');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(productPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      const products = JSON.parse(data);
      resolve({
        props: { products },
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Don't `throw err`. Reject the promise instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
   export function getStaticProps() {
        return fetch(
            "myapilink.com/api"
        ).then((response) =>
            response.json().then((data) => {
                return { props: { data } };
            })
        );
    }
```